# Can't activate VPN on cascaded Asus router due to private WAN IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, ddns

I have a cascade of routers with LAN-to-WAN connection, both routers work fine, I can use Internet etc, but for the reason I don't understand, I can't activate OpenVPN on my second router. Even though, in my previous apartments I was able to activate VPN and connect to Internet through it.

I have different IP addresses on my two routers: 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1, DHCP is enabled on the second router. Here's the error message I get: [image: Here's the error message I get]

VPN connection status:
[image]

Comment: This is unclear : Why are you trying to setup a VPN *server* on the second router? Will you be trying to access it from the internet? Note also that the DDNS client service may not be able to work under multi-layer NAT network.

Comment: I need stable VPN, that's it. Yes, I'll access internet through the VPN server.

Comment: You misunderstand - the VPN server is for use by clients on other computers. It serves for nothing to have server and client on the same router. You need a VPN server on the public internet, either free or paid.

Comment: I have a paid VPN server, I used openVPN to create a file with VPN settings for the router.

Comment: Why do you need to cascade the routers?  Understanding that might help us help you.